# WebView leaks entire Activities - with a simple example!

Tags: android

I'm starting to notice, that, even on honeycomb, you'll leak an entire Activity and WebView if you're using WebView and you rotate your phone a few times.

I've got some test code here for proof:

```
public class WebViewTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private WebView mWeb;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWeb = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mWeb.destroy();
        mWeb = null; // just making sure.
    }
}
```

This seems simple enough, but if you launch the app, rotate your device a few times, and then dump an hprof to view it in MAT or something similar, you'll see two things:

First, there are **two** instances of WebViewTestActivity hanging around, and **two** instances of WebView.  This seems to be the case no matter how many times you rotate your device.

This seems like a huge problem, leaking an entire Activity, and I've googled it to no avail.  I see several complaints about this issue, but no official responses or workarounds.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Edit: MAT screenshots of shortest path to GC roots, excluding soft, weak, and phantom references: http://vimtips.org/media/mat.png

Edit: I was wrong, this bug is fixed in Gingerbread and up.  Wish there was a way to work around it in previous releases.

Comment: Is it the same in 2.3.3 as a comparison?

Comment: perhaps WebViewFragment fixes it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you dump an HPROF file does not mean that every possible object has magically gotten garbage collected. The Dalvik GC engine, in the interests of minimizing CPU impact, does not clean the entire heap space of garbage on every collection pass, and dumping an HPROF file does not change that.

Hence, MAT will report objects that simply have not been garbage collected. This is not "a huge problem, leaking an entire Activity".

You need to use MAT to find the roots for those objects -- if there are none, then they simply have not yet been garbage collected. If, however, you do see that they are being referenced by something (e.g., in the OS), then there may be a problem.

---

**UPDATE**

Now that we see the roots in question...

The first one is not in the Android source code as shown on Google Code Search. By which, I mean there is no `mCurrentMainWebView` in the [`JWebCoreJavaBridge`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/webkit/JWebCoreJavaBridge.java&q=BrowserFrame%20package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org&d=4) class or anywhere in the source code. There *is* a static `sCurrentMainWebView`, but that is a `WeakReference`. Either that problem is with a different version of Android than the one I'm looking at, or a device manufacturer hacked something.

The second one is strange. There is an `mContext` data member in [`WebViewCore`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewCore.java&q=WebViewCore%20package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc); however, it is not static. In fact, `WebViewCore` has no mutable static data members that I see. It is conceivable that this is something tied to `WebViewCore`'s use of JNI, or this again may be a discrepancy between the source code I am looking at and the code that is running on your device or emulator.

Comment: @synic: No, I did not try it -- that information should have been in your question from the outset. Lots of people complain about Android leaks that are not there. I will edit my answer momentarily.

Comment: Hrmm, I have two devices, the G2 running what's supposedly stock 2.2, and the Xoom running 3.0.1.  Looks like I was wrong about this problem existing in Honeycomb.  I thought I had seen it on the Xoom, but I can't reproduce it now.  I can consistently reproduce it on my G2.  Because in the Froyo sourcecode, I do see the mCurrentMainWebView in JWebCoreJavaBride (http://preview.tinyurl.com/3efpj88), it appears to be a bug they fixed sometime between Eclair and Honeycomb.  I guess I am one of those complainers :)

Comment: @synic: Well, if it's `mCurrentWebView` in Froyo, then it was fixed in Gingerbread, because `mCurrentWebView` is the bug. I think Google Code Search indexes the `master` branch, so I was probably looking at the Gingerbread code. Surprised that problem lasted this long.